# Page reloads after my javascript is executed, I dont want it to

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

When my javascript is executed, the script executes properly. However the sharepoint notification it produces is supposed to simply fade out after 3 seconds, but instead, after ~2 seconds, the whole page reloads.

**How can I prevent the page from reloading after my script executes?**

I have the following javascript in my `usercontrol.ascx`:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MoodPanelNy.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl" %>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function MyJavascript() {
                // Displays Notification
                var notification = 'Your answer has been submitted, thanks!';
                var notificationId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(notification);
            }
        </script>
```

This is my code behind's method `Page_Load` which binds the script to a button:

```
NotificationButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return MyJavascript();");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "notification", strScript, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try update:

```
NotificationButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "MyJavascript(); return false;");
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "notification", strScript, true);
```

You should use `return false;` to prevent form post.

Comment: you could also add the `return false` to the `MyJavascript` method to accomplish the same thing.